# Is there a way to get a multiplexing terminal on RHEL 7 Atomic?

Tags: rhel7

I would like to ssh to an instance of RHEL 7 Atomic and have multiple persistent terminals open on it (so that if my connection is lost, I can ssh back in and pick up where I left off). Normally I use screen for this, but tmux and probably others normally provide such capability. It seems like an obvious thing to have, but I can't find it on this platform.

The restrictions on RHEL 7 Atomic:

- Very little is installed
- No ability to install packages with yum / rpm
- Cannot update OS to anything except official Red Hat images
- No ability to compile anything

What's a good way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I am just blind. tmux is installed on Atomic.